# css animation moves page - fix page scroll position on current element with css?

Tags: javascript, css

Given the following simplified problem:

```
foreach i in 1..100 do
    <div onclick="$("div").attr('class','expand');">block i</div>
```

And this css:

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

div.expand {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Now when I click on a div, every div get's the class "expand". This means that the page will expand. However, everything will scroll down. That means that if I click on div 50, it will probably not be in my window anymore and I have to scroll down to see it again.

I would love to make the div that I clicked on stay in the center of the screen. Is this possible with CSS, or do I need JS?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible ... you can use jQuery's `.scrollTop()` method like this:

```
$(window).scrollTop( $('.your_element').offset().top + $('.your_element').height() - $(window).height() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This function scrolls the page according to the position of mouseclick:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(e){
        var offsetY = e.pageY -  $(window).scrollTop();
        $('div').attr('class','expand');
        $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top-offsetY);
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/uRFg7/) on jsFiddle